# How to upgrade a project to the recent SVN Version in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

I am trying to upgrade my project to the most recent version in IntelliJ. I have configured my SVN repository and I have tried various ways of upgrading it, without success: I am choosing Update Project and then the following dialog shows up:

[image]

After clicking the **OK** button it says that the files are up-to-date **but the files in my project are not upgraded at all;** they are the same as they used to be before the 'update'.

[image]

I've went through several [documentation online](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/update-project-dialog-subversion.html) but I didn't have any success. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck the "Update/Switch to specific revision" checkbox in the dialog. As long as it is checked, IntelliJ IDEA will update to the specified revision, not to the latest one.

Comment: I also tried deleting the file but it won't get deleted even if I try to..

Comment: The list on the left in the dialog shows multiple repositories. You need to select them all and ensure that the checkbox is unchecked for each repository.